# Howto sign a pdf with iText with a PKCS1 signature

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, sign

I need to sign pdf documents using an external service which will return a PKCS1 signature. This means i do have to add the public key in an IExternalSignatureContainer instance. I'm using iText 7 for the whole signing process.

There is a good example for this approach on the [iText website](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signatures-chapter-4)

I did implement this example but instead of using a service for signing the hash value, i do it with a X509 Certificate. The problem is that the signature is somehow invalid (It says the document was altered after signing). The certificates seem to be correct integrated.
[image]

I have created an example of the whole singing process in one file.
Required references:

- BouncyCastle.Crypto
- itext.kernel
- itext.sign

The (self signed) public keys, private key and an example of a signed pdf document can be downloaded here: http://www.filedropper.com/pdfsignfiles

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Sample Code(two classes in one file ready for a console application):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Signatures;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using X509Certificate = Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate;

namespace SignExternalTestManuel
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            string filePath = @"c:\temp\pdfsign\";
            string pdfToSign = Path.Combine(filePath, @"test.pdf");
            string destinationFile = Path.Combine(filePath, "test_signed.pdf");
            string userCertificatePublicKey = Path.Combine(filePath, "BITSignTestManuel5Base64.cer");
            string caCertificatePublicKey = Path.Combine(filePath, "BITRoot5Base64.cer");
            string privateKeyFile = Path.Combine(filePath, "BITSignTestManuel5.pfx");
            string privateKeyPassword =  "test";

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfToSign);
            using (FileStream os = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                StampingProperties stampingProperties = new StampingProperties();
                //For any signature in the Pdf  but the first one, you need to use appendMode
                //        stampingProperties.useAppendMode();
                stampingProperties.UseAppendMode();
                PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(reader, os, stampingProperties);
                pdfSigner.SetCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);

                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new GsSignatureContainer(
                    PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                    PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached,
                    userCertificatePublicKey,
                    caCertificatePublicKey,
                    privateKeyFile,
                    privateKeyPassword);
                pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(external, 32000);
            }

        }
    }
    public class GsSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
    {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private string userCertificatePublicKey;
        private string caCertificatePublicKey;
        private string privateKeyFile;
        private string privateKeyPassword;

        public GsSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter, string userCertificatePublicKey, string caCertificatePublicKey, string privateKeyFile, string privateKeyPassword)
        {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.Put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.Put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
            this.userCertificatePublicKey = userCertificatePublicKey;
            this.caCertificatePublicKey = caCertificatePublicKey;
            this.privateKeyFile = privateKeyFile;
            this.privateKeyPassword = privateKeyPassword;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Implementation based on https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/how-to-use-a-digital-signing-service-dss-such-as-globalsign-with-itext-7#HowtouseaDigitalSigningService(DSS)suchasGlobalSign,withiText7-Examplecode
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pdfStream"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public byte[] Sign(Stream pdfStream)
        {
            //Create the certificate chaing since the signature is just a PKCS1, the certificates must be added to the signature
            string cert = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(userCertificatePublicKey);
            string ca = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(caCertificatePublicKey);
            X509Certificate[] chain = CreateChain(cert, ca);

            String hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;
            PdfPKCS7 pkcs7Signature = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, false);

            //Create the hash of of the pdf document
            byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(pdfStream, DigestAlgorithms.GetMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));


            //TODO: Unclear whether i need to use this. It is from the example, but maybe only required for 
            //byte[] sh = pkcs7Signature.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
            //using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            //{
            //    sh = sha256.ComputeHash(hash);
            //}

            //Create the actual signautre (This will be done via Service)
            byte[] signature = CreateSignature(hash, privateKeyFile, privateKeyPassword);

            pkcs7Signature.SetExternalDigest(signature, null, "RSA");

            return pkcs7Signature.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
        }

        public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
        {
            signDic.PutAll(sigDic);
        }

        private static X509Certificate[] CreateChain(String cert, String ca)
        {
            //Note: The root certificate could be omitted and it would still work
            X509Certificate[] chainy = new X509Certificate[2];
            X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
            chainy[0] = new X509Certificate(parser.ReadCertificate(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cert))
                .CertificateStructure);
            chainy[1] = new X509Certificate(parser.ReadCertificate(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ca))
                .CertificateStructure);
            return chainy;
        }

        #region "Create signature, will be done by an actual service"
        private byte[] CreateSignature(byte[] hash, string privateKeyFile, string privateKeyPassword)
        {
            X509Certificate2 rootCertificateWithPrivateKey = new X509Certificate2();
            byte[] rawData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(privateKeyFile);
            rootCertificateWithPrivateKey.Import(rawData, privateKeyPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            using (var key = rootCertificateWithPrivateKey.GetRSAPrivateKey())
            {
                return key.SignData(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
            }
        }

        #endregion


    }
}
```

Comment: *"I need to sign pdf documents using an external service which will return a PKCS1 signature. This means i do have to add the public key in an IExternalSignatureContainer instance"* - hhmmmm. No. For pkcs#1 you usually need an `IExternalSignature` instance. You *can* use an `IExternalSignatureContainer` but you don't have to.

Comment: Is there a reason to use IExternalSignature over IExternalSignatureContainer?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't have run into the issue at hand, you wouldn't have forgotten to do what you mention in your answer... *because iText would have done that for you under the hood*! On the other hand using `IExternalSignature` is not always better than `IExternalSignatureContainer`; for example it does not support RSASSA-PSS and only incompletely supports ECDSA, so in related use cases you don't want to use `IExternalSignature`.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem in my code.
I was signing the hash value directly without using GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes. The signature becomes valid as soon as i add the following code and then sign sh instead of hash:

```
            //Create the hash based on the document hash which is suitable for pdf siging
            X509Certificate2 rootCertificateWithoutPrivateKey = new X509Certificate2();
            rootCertificateWithoutPrivateKey.Import(caCertificatePublicKey);
            X509Certificate rootCertBouncy = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(rootCertificateWithoutPrivateKey);
            List<X509Certificate> c = new List<X509Certificate>();
            c.Add(rootCertBouncy);
            PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, c.ToArray(), hashAlgorithm, false);
            byte[] sh = sgn.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```